# Convert a Matrix{Num} to Matrix{Int64} after substituting all symbolic variables in Julia

Tags: casting, julia, symbolic-math

When using symbolics.jl, matrices with variables are of type `Matrix{Num}`. However, even after substituting all variables, the type is still `Matrix{Num}` -- How can I convert this into a `Matrix{Int64}`?

Consider the following example:

```
using Symbolics
@variables t

symbolic_mtx = [t 2; 3 4] # this matrix has a symbolic entry
println(typeof(symbolic_mtx)) # prints Matrix{Num}, as expected

# now we plug t=1 in
numeric_mtx = substitute(symbolic_mtx, Dict(t => 1))
println(typeof(numeric_mtx)) # still prints Matrix{Num}!
```

This uses substitute as [recommended here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/numerically-evaluate-a-symbolic-expression/73816/2), but does not work -- the type is still `Matrix{Num}`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: After substituting, one needs to reference the values by using `Symbolics.value`. In the case of a matrix as in the question, we need to broadcast, so that the following works:

```
numeric_mtx = Symbolics.value.(substitute(symbolic_mtx, Dict(t => 1))) 
println(typeof(numeric_mtx)) # still prints Matrix{Int64}
```